# login page in ajax and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im newer in ajax and codeigniter.. I am developing ajax login form. I create view controller and module form. when i click the submit button in login form its not working. I checked in the console.log() there is no error showing. Can any one pls solve my problem..Thanks in advance..

This is my view page.Ajaxlogin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Meta tag for IE -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>Helen Flaghrity Charitable Society</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css");?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/admin.css");?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/font-awesome.min.css");?>" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid login">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div> 
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div id="logerror"></div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Admin</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="" method="post" id="frm_login">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="adminname">Admin Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adminname" id="adminname" placeholder="Admin Name" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="adminpassword">Password</label>
           <input type="password" class="form-control" name="adminpassword" id="adminpassword" placeholder="Password" required="required">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div><!-- script queries-->
</div>
<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery.min.js");?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.min.js");?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/script.js");?>"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Ajaxlogin/Admin_login');?>",
            type: "post",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
            if (data== 'true')
            {   
               alert("success");
            }
            else{
               alert("Invalid Userid or password");
            }
         }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller page. Ajaxlogin.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajaxlogin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Ajaxmodel');
    }
    public function index()
    {

           $this->load->view('Ajaxlogin');

    }
    public function Admin_login(){
        $name = $this->input->post('adminname');
        $password= $this->input->post('adminpassword');
        $result=$this->Ajaxmodel->login($name,$password);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            echo "true";
        }
  }

 }
```

This is my model Page Ajaxmodel.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajaxmodel extends CI_Model{
    public function login($name,$password) {
        $name=$name;
        $password=md5($password);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('admin');
        $this->db->where('name',$name);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to catch error (in ajax): 
                error : function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Some error, see console');
                    console.log("xhr",xhr);
                    console.log("textStatus",textStatus);
                    console.log("errorThrown",errorThrown);
                }

Answer (score 0):

i think you should prevent default action on form submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Ajaxlogin/Admin_login');?>",
            type: "post",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
            if (data== 'true')
            {   
               alert("success");
            }
            else{
               alert("Invalid Userid or password");
            }
         }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```